# flask-apscheduler make flask command not stop

Tags: python, flask

I use **flask run** to activate my flask app.

And I will register some period function by flask-apscheduler.

The problem is I also create some self-defined flask command, and

if I run command in shell like **flask my-self-defined-command** .

Command won't stop since I register some function in create_app procedure.

Is any way to identify using **flask run** command?

Any other idea?

ps. I cant use flask hook *app.before_first_request*, I need my period work run when flask is running.